# How do I replace a portion of a string using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a street name `"2839 WYATT WY"`. I want to replace the second `'WY'` with `'WAY'`

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Im new to regex I just tried the replace function which obviously does not work.

Comment: Is `WY` always at the end of your string and is the only thing you want to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to substitute `WY`, which is always at the end of your string with `WAY`, then you can do with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re) module using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub) method:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "2839 WYATT WY"
>>> re.sub(r'\bWY$', 'WAY', s)
'2839 WYATT WAY'
```

**EDIT:** For general cases of where `'WY'` could be in the string, this is an improved solution

```
>>> s = "2839 WYATT WY WYSE"
>>>>
>>> re.sub(r'\bWY\b', 'WAY', s)
'2839 WYATT WAY WYSE'
>>> s = "2839 WYATT WY"
>>> re.sub(r'\bWY\b', 'WAY', s)
'2839 WYATT WAY'
```

Comment: Thank you! That is perfect! Out of curiosity what if 'WY' is not at the end but say it appears like so "2839 WYATT WY WYSE"

Comment: so, I assume you want to replace `'WY'` not within `'WYSE'` ?

Comment: Yes I only want to replace 'WY' in the middle of the string not in WYATT or WYSE

Comment: Check my edit @debugged

Comment: @debugged .. no pblm..I've posted the link for `re` module in Python Doc, read it.